# GCP: How to implement "gcloud alpha firestore export ..." shell command through Google's Python API client

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud, google-api-python-client

I have been running

```
gcloud alpha firestore export ...
```

to export certain collections in Firestore to GCS. Now I want to implement this with Google's [Python API package](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client), but I can't find good examples to refer to.

Or am I looking at the wrong repo?

Answer (score 1):

There is no a direct function in the client libraries to do so ( Firestore GIT [[1]](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/tree/master/firestore) ), but, as there is an API call that do so [[2]](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/firestore/m/firestore/v1beta1/firestore.projects.databases.exportDocuments), you can call it using Python and `google-api-python-client`[[3]](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/). Here you can find the method details [[4]](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/firestore/v1beta1/python/latest/firestore_v1beta1.projects.databases.html#exportDocuments).

Anyway, I filed a Feature Request [[5]](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112827824) on your behalf for you to follow it.